# Derivative with respect to a variable that is in the region of integration

Tags: calculus, integration, integral-domain

I need to calculate $f(k)=\frac{dg(k)}{dk}$, where

$g(k)=\iiint_{\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:h(x,y,z)\leq k\}}e^{-(x+y+z)}dxdydz$

$h(x,y,z)\leq k$ is the domain of integration (and quite nasty, by the way). Obviously, integrating first and later differentiating does not work (too complicated). I have to solve it numerically and later look for a sound fit. If I get a fit for $g(k)$ and then differentiate to obtain an approximation for $f(k)$, it does not work very well.

Comment: what do you know about $h$?

Comment: Thanks for your interest @uniquesolution.

$h(x,y,z)=\sqrt{\left(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y-z}{y+z}\right)^2+\left(\frac{x-z}{x+z}\right)^2}$

Comment: I don't understand why the expression for $h$ in my previous comment is not compiled... Sorry if it's not clear.

Comment: It seems that the third term causes trouble. Try writing it again.

Comment: Let's see:

$h(x,y,z)=\sqrt{(\frac{x-y}{x+y})^2+(\frac{y-z}{y+z})^2+(\frac{x-z}{x+z})^2}$

Comment: Oh , I see. Looks rather intimidating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute $g(k+\mathrm dk)-g(k)$ to the first order in $\mathrm dk$. This gives
$$g(k+\mathrm dk)-g(k)=\iiint_{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3,\; k\leq h(x,y,z)\leq k+\mathrm dk}\mathrm e^{-x-y-z}\;\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz$$
The domain $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3,\; k\leq h(x,y,z)\leq k+\mathrm dk\}$ is a domain in space delimited by two surfaces $h(x,y,z)=k$ and $h(x,y,z)=k+\mathrm dk$. This volume is a "thickened" surface of thickness equal to $\epsilon(x,y,z)=\mathrm dk/\|\nabla h(x,y,z)\|$. You can rewrite
$$g(k+\mathrm dk)-g(k)=\iiint_{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3,\; h(x,y,z)=k}
\epsilon(x,y,z)\mathrm e^{-x-y-z}\;\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz.$$
Keeping the first order in $\mathrm dk$ you get
$$\frac{\mathrm dg}{\mathrm dk}=\iiint_{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3,\; h(x,y,z)=k}
\mathrm e^{-x-y-z}\frac{\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz}{\|\nabla h(x,y,z)\|}.$$

Beware that the integral is performed now on a surface...

Comment: thanks!

Very powerful (and to me unknown) strategy. I'm dealing now with the complexity of $||\nabla h(x,y,z)||$. I posted in a comment above how $h$ looks like and that is not simple.